# CheckListBox item style

Tags: delphi

I add items on startup (filenames from a given folder's name) and I'm using this procedure to make things done when clicking items:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBoxClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
```

how to make the checked item to change its color or style? In other words I click an item and I what to be **bold** after check.

Comment: kobik's answer is the best. I have ABSOLUTELY nothing to comment against it. but if you are inexperienced with Delphi to create "complex" custom-drawing code like that, there is also a hack-like alternative: compose your own CheckListBox: put multiple checkboxes in a TPanel or TScrollBox and align them to top. This way you have access to each checkbox properties (font color, face, size, etc) - Remember this is just a dirty hack. But it will work with Delphi styles (vsf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `Style` property to `lbOwnerDrawFixed` and draw the items yourself in the `OnDrawItem` event.

e.g.

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl;
  Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  Flags: Longint;
begin
  with TCheckListBox(Control) do
  begin
    if Checked[Index] then
    begin
      Canvas.Font.Style := Canvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
      Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
    end;
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    if Index < Items.Count then
    begin
      Flags := DrawTextBiDiModeFlags(DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_NOPREFIX);
      if not UseRightToLeftAlignment then
        Inc(Rect.Left, 2)
      else
        Dec(Rect.Right, 2);
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Items[Index]), Length(Items[Index]), Rect,
        Flags);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1ClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCheckListBox(Sender).Invalidate;
end;
```

Note the `Invalidate` in the `OnClickCheck` is also needed since that the control is not invalidated when an item is checked/unchecked (at-least not in my current Delphi version).

Comment: What a nasty usage of `with`. I'm refering to `State:  TOwnerDrawState` versus `TCheckListBox(Control).State`. But, correct however.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something because it doesn't work for me. I've even created a new project and added only TCheckListBox component with 5 items manually added  and those two procedures.There is no effect when clicking.

Comment: Yes, I click the checkbox of an item in the CheckListBox.

Comment: Did you set the style as instructed by the answer?

Comment: good point, sorry I missed that before, now works fine! Thanks! it seems I don't need this `TCheckListBox(Sender).Invalidate;`

Comment: @TomBrunberg, "What a nasty usage of with..." - Yeah I know. is it better now? :-P Also note, the `State: TOwnerDrawState` is not useful here since the `odChecked` is not set at all.

Comment: Yeah, heh, it's better now.

Comment: @kobik Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

@Felix
Kobik's answer is the best. I have ABSOLUTELY nothing to comment against it.

But if you are inexperienced with Delphi to create "complex" custom-drawing code like that, there is also a hack-like alternative: compose your own CheckListBox: put multiple checkboxes in a TPanel or TScrollBox and align them to top. This way you have access to each checkbox properties (font face, size, style, etc).
Many new controls can be created this way, from composite controls.

Remember this is just an alternative/**dirty hack**. Yes. It will work with Delphi styles (vsf).